# Can someone provide the REST api or powershell script for the MT4 Manager API account creation, deposit/withdrawals?

Tags: metatrader4, mt4

Please provide the REST api for MT4 Manager API or the powershell example.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at this library:

- https://cplugin.com/projects/tools/mt4manapi-net
- "This is a library for .NET, a wrapper for native MetaQuotes Manager API to work with MT4 server using any language that supports .NET."
- You can get access to your MT4 server using any of these great languages: C#, Visual Basic .NET, JavaScript, .NET C++/CLI (Managed C++), F#, J#, PowerShell, Python for .NET (pythonnet)

Some other possible resources:

- https://github.com/SFEXGlobal/MT4ManagerAPP
- https://github.com/SFEXGlobal/MT4TradeAPP
- https://sergeylukashevich.github.io/mt-access-doc/#introduction
- https://github.com/dingmaotu/mql4-lib
- https://github.com/dingmaotu/mt4-server
- https://github.com/mikha-dev/mt4-rest
- https://github.com/vdemydiuk/mtapi